# How can I find the ID of a google sheet that I've just created with code?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've just created a copy of a file with a new name using this command:

```
file.makeCopy(''+newfilename+'');
```

How can I find the ID of the new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you check the official documentation, you will see that [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopy) returns an object of the class [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#).**

The latter has a method [getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getid) which gives you the id of the `File`.

```
const newFile = file.makeCopy('newfilename'); // it returns an object of type File
const newFileID = newFile.getId(); // File has a method .getId()
```

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but I'm not a professional coder. This is what I've just done:  
  file.makeCopy(''+newfilename+'');  
  const newFile=file.makeCopy(''+newfilename+'');
  const newFileID = newFile.getId()   file.makeCopy(''+newfilename+'');  
  I can intuit that this was not what you had in mind but am not sure how to connect my creation of the file with the getID() in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
```

Comment: That gives me the ID for the SS I'm in; I need the ID for the NEW SS I've created using code within my current SS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
var copy = file.makeCopy('Put the new file name here');
var id = copy.getId();
```

Related

- [Get document's URL/ID after a file was copied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41071264/1595451)
- [makeCopy() function to return URL and Title of the copied file from user drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55024923/1595451)